# Unexpected behavior of enum

Tags: c#, enums

I implemented a method with `System.Drawing.RotateFlipType` and got a strange behaviour while comparing values.

```
System.Drawing.RotateFlipType item1 = System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;
System.Drawing.RotateFlipType item2 = System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY;
Console.WriteLine(item1 == item2); //true
```

How could this be true?

Comment: If you think about it, it makes sense. "Specifies a 180-degree clockwise rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical flip." Do that transformation in your head, and you end up back where you started.

Comment: @canton7 then you could also leave this complicate transformation off instead of confuse developers :)

Comment: They could, but then developers might wonder why there's a `Rotate180FlipX` and `Rotate180FlipY` and `RotateNoneFlipXY` but no `Rotate180FlipXY`.

Comment: @canton7 if you see Wai Ha Lee's answer, they could just leave off the whole `Y-Flip` stuff and all would be fine without duplicates. If your point is consistency, they could also add anti-clockwise rotation so you have values for one enum

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not on the .NET BCL design team, and I can only speculate as to their reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086121/canton7) pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749958/unexpected-behavior-of-enum/54750005#comment96282194_54749958),

> If you think about it, it makes sense. "Specifies a 180-degree clockwise rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical flip." Do that transformation in your head, and you end up back where you started.

For that reason, the `RotateFlipType` values `RotateNoneFlipNone` and `Rotate180FlipXY` both have the same value (of `0`) ([API source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rotatefliptype?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

This is made apparent in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/RotateFlipType.cs,411a902f64927391) (with the XML comments elided):

```
public enum RotateFlipType
{
    RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,
    Rotate90FlipNone   = 1,
    Rotate180FlipNone  = 2,
    Rotate270FlipNone  = 3,
    RotateNoneFlipX    = 4,
    Rotate90FlipX      = 5,
    Rotate180FlipX     = 6,
    Rotate270FlipX     = 7,
    RotateNoneFlipY    = Rotate180FlipX,
    Rotate90FlipY      = Rotate270FlipX,
    Rotate180FlipY     = RotateNoneFlipX,
    Rotate270FlipY     = Rotate90FlipX,
    RotateNoneFlipXY   = Rotate180FlipNone,
    Rotate90FlipXY     = Rotate270FlipNone,
    Rotate180FlipXY    = RotateNoneFlipNone,
    Rotate270FlipXY    = Rotate90FlipNone
}
```

There's no harm in having the duplicates, so I suppose it makes it easier for the consumers of the enum to have multiple definitions for the same thing.

In fact there's no reason that you can't have duplicate numeric values for enum values - in fact the C# language specification [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums):

> Multiple enum members may share the same associated value. The example
>
> ```
> enum Color 
> {
>     Red,
>     Green,
>     Blue,
>     Max = Blue
> }
> ```
>
> shows an enum in which two enum members—`Blue` and `Max`—have the same associated value.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to leave off the `FlipY` stuff to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Then you'd have to do some extra thinking to consider if the two operations are the same. If you're writing something that has logic depending on what the values are, you'd probably use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) statement - in which case you'd get a compiler error if you tried to introduce two `case` entries with the same value.

Comment: @Dr.Snail that's thinking in the wrong direction. Fewer people need to consume the enum than use it. It's much handier just to ask for the transformation you want than go "oh, it doesn't have `Rotate90FlipY`lemme see [sketch on paper] I wonder if it has `Rotate270FlipX`, ah it does, good".

Answer (score 3):

`RotateNoneFlipNone` and `RotateNoneFlipXY` both have value `0`.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Specifies no clockwise rotation and no flipping.
RotateNoneFlipNone = 0,
//
// Summary:
//     Specifies a 180-degree clockwise rotation followed by a horizontal and vertical
//     flip.
Rotate180FlipXY = 0,
```

There are actually more of them, and it makes perfectly sense. Like rotating 270 clockwise or 90 anti-clockwise, it is all the same.

Comment: funfact _180-degree clockwise rotation_ shouldn't be a difference to a _180-degree anti-clockwise rotation_

Answer (score 0):

The values are the same, take a look here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rotatefliptype?view=netframework-4.7.2